# Windows PowerShell Make two lines one line

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a very large log file that I want to search through. Some of the long lines are broke out into two line. I would like to take the second line of those lines and concatenate it to the previous line so they are all on the same line again.

The file looks like this:

```
05/10 some text
05/10 some text
05/10 some text
05/10 some really long text that goes to
the second line
05/10 some text 
05/10 some text
05/10 some really long text that goes to 
the second line
```

I would like the file to look like this:

```
05/10 some text
05/10 some text
05/10 some text
05/10 some really long text that goes to the second line
05/10 some text 
05/10 some text
05/10 some really long text that goes to the second line
```

Comment: `(Get-Content 'C:\temp\file.txt' -Raw) -replace '\r\n(?!\d{2}\/\d{2})' | Set-Content 'c:\temp\newfile.txt'`

Comment: @AnthonyStringer I was about to post the answer with the same (not even a single character different) regex you provided :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework for doing this is fairly simple.  Iterate over the lines outputting as you go, and when one needs to be combined, concatenate them before moving on.

```
$collector = $null
@(switch -file $filename {
  { isNewLine($_) } { 
    # Start of new line.
    # Output the current collector, and reinitialize with the new line.
    $collector
    $collector = $_
  }
  default {
    # Continuation of previous line.  Add current to collector.
    $collector += $_ 
  }
}, $collector) | Out-File $outputFile
```

The tricky part is how to define the function `isNewLine`.  For example, if a "good" line always starts with the text `05/10` you can use:

```
function isNewLine([string]$line) {
  $line.startsWith('05/10')
}
```

Or more generally, if it always starts with a date of the form `MM/dd`, you can use the regex.

```
function isNewLine([string]$line) {
  $line -match '^\d{2}/\d{2}'
}
```

The structure is slightly different if you need to check the end of a line instead of the beginning.  For example, if any line longer than 80 characters is combined with the next line

```
$collector = $null
@(switch -file $filename {
  { $_.length -ge 80 } { 
    # Line continues on next.  Save to collector
    $collector += $_
  }
  default {
    # Line doesn't continue.  Output it and clear collector
    $collector + $_
    $collector = $null
  }
}, $collector) | Out-File $outputFile
```

Comment: All the good lines start with the date, so I can deal with using 05 and so on. I will try it out and let you know, thanks.

Comment: What did I do wrong, it doesn't seem to put anything out to my new file. `code $filename = 'file1.log'
$outputFile = 'file2.txt'

function isNewLine([string]$line) {
  $line.startsWith('05')
}

$collector = $null
switch -file $filename {
  { isNewLine($_) } { 
    # Start of new line.
    # Output the current collector, and reinitialize with the new line.
    $collector
    $collector = $_
  }
  default {
    # Continuation of previous line.  Add current to collector.
    $collector += $_ 
  }
} $collector | Out-File $outputFile code`

Comment: Looks like I missed a parenthesis necessary to pipe it out to `Out-File`.  Because I tried to add `$collector` to the end, I need to wrap the whole switch in `@( ... )`.  See correction above.